# curl login on Https asp page

Tags: php, curl, https, asp-classic

I am trying to log into an .asp site with a https login page from PHP. I can't get logged into the site . There dosen't seem to be a cookie generated, viewstate, etc nor does it work leaving these parameters out. The form fields seem to fill correctly (i can physically see the login name) but im not sure about the password field which is a password type, but i don't think there is a issue there, its correctly spelled etc.

I have tried all the related posts including http://www.mishainthecloud.com/2009/12/screen-scraping-aspnet-application-in.html?showComment=1368565341638#c9104469935977149435

My code is below and returning "not Found" (error code 7 i think..) on the final call. No curl errors are present on the 1st two calls.

Can anyone help with this?

```
$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE"); 

// URL to login page 
$url = "https://secure2.clubwise.com/glenview/memberlogin.asp"; 

// Get Login page and its cookies/ viewstate , etc
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile); // no cookie stored 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
//print(esc_html($output));

$viewstate = regexExtract($output,$regexViewstate,$regs,1);
$eventval = regexExtract($output, $regexEventVal,$regs,1);

// rebuild post info -- view state and eventvalidate empty! cant find on page
$fields_string =  
'__VIEWSTATE='.rawurlencode($viewstate).
'&__EVENTVALIDATION='.rawurlencode($eventval).
'&login='.urlencode('xxx@xxx.com'). 
'&password='.urlencode('xxxx').
'&submit='.urlencode('Sign in').
'&redirect='; 

echo $fields_string;

// Post login form -- password field ok?
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Accepts all CAs 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 5); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // Tells cURL to follow redirects 
$outputb = curl_exec($ch); 
print curl_error;
//var_dump($outputb);


$url = "https://secure2.clubwise.com/glenview/bookclass.asp"; 
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$outputc = curl_exec($ch); 
print curl_error;
var_dump($outputc);
```

header information:

```
//$header= array(
//'HTTP/1.1 200 OK',
//'Date: Mon, 09 Jun 2014 00:55:17',
//'GMT Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0',
//'X-Powered-By: ASP.NET',
//'Content-Length: 21035',
//'Content-Type: text/html',
//'Set-Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDCCSBSTDC=IHJBDOOBIDMJDDOFLAOOBENL; path=/',
//'Cache-control: private'

//);
```

SOLUTION: it was curl_init() on each operation that was causing this to break. Viewstate, headers are not needed.

```
$ourFileName = get_stylesheet_directory()."/cookieFile.txt";
$ckfile = $ourFileName; 

// URL to login page 
$url = "https://secure2.clubwise.com/glenview/memberlogin.asp"; 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Accepts all CAs 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile); // Stores cookies in the temp file 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

$output = curl_exec($ch); 

//Cookie obtained, login 
$fields_string =  
'&redirect='.
'&login='.urlencode('vvv@xxx.com'). 
'&password='.urlencode('xxx').
'&submit='.urlencode('"Sign in"' )
; 

//cookie in the header + header not required
/*
$cookielines =file($ckfile);
foreach($cookielines as $row) {
if($row[0] != '#') {
    $cookie=$row;
    }
}


$header= array( // not needed at moment

'HTTP/1.1 200 OK',
'Date: Mon, 09 Jun 2014 00:55:17',
'GMT Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0',
'X-Powered-By: ASP.NET',
'Content-Length: 21035',
'Content-Type: text/html',
'Set-Cookie: $cookie; path=/',
'Cache-control: private'

);

*/

$url = "https://secure2.clubwise.com/glenview/memberlogin.asp"; 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Accepts all CAs 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 4); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile); //Uses cookies from the temp file 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // Tells cURL to follow redirects 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,""); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,"https://secure2.clubwise.com/glenview/memberlogin.asp");
$outputb = curl_exec($ch); 

$err = curl_errno ( $ch ); echo "<br>error=".$err;
$errmsg = curl_error ( $ch ); echo "<br>errmsg=".$errmsg;
$header = curl_getinfo ( $ch ); echo "<br>header="; var_dump($header);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo ( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE ); echo "<br>httpcode=".$httpCode;

print curl_error;
```

//Now you should be able to access any pages within the password-restricted area by just including the cookies for each call:

```
$url = "https://secure2.clubwise.com/glenview/bookclass.asp?Mode=Area&RecId=67"; 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Accepts all CAs 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile); //Uses cookies from the temp file 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$outputc = curl_exec($ch); 
print curl_error;

var_dump($outputc);
```

Comment: `$fields` is not defined in `count($fields)`, so try replacing `count($fields)` with `5`

Comment: no unfortunately not, i was using a array as to build the query string in the same way hence the typo :( . You dont know if you can find viewstate / eventvalidation using chrome or firebug? i dont use asp so not familiar with it.

Comment: Just a tip: I don't see usual browser headers like Pragme, Cache-Control, Referer. Maybe they are checking against these. I'm not sure, but its worth a try.

Comment: thanks mate, i updated the header info from tamperhead on the bottom but when i try it it gives invalid header name, i dont see pragme or referrer, any ideas?

Comment: have you tried to use " Sign in " as value for the submit Parameter? because when you look at the source code of the Webpage there are " " in the value... sometimes classic asp developers check against the value of the submit button...

Comment: just checked it there, thats not working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check again that cookie stored on first page. Set `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` for Session cookies and not reinit or close curl for save a session.
Set `CURLOPT_REFERER`, some sites check it for login page.

Comment: thats it!! it was the curl_init on each operation that was the issue, thanks a mill :)